# What happens when RCSI is enabled in one database but not another, and you query both?

Tags: sql-server, transaction, isolation-level

Suppose that I have two databases on the same server, `RCSI_Yes` and `RSCI_No`. In the first, RCSI is enabled. In the second, it is not. How does SQL Server decide what transaction isolation level should be used when I write a query that hits both databases? Does it matter which databases I run my query from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does SQL Server decide what transaction isolation level should be
> used when I write a query that hits both databases?

The isolation level used is "read committed" - the locking vs snapshot are different implementations of this isolation level.

Regarding what flavour it uses it won't have any choice other than to use the locking flavour if querying a database that has the option disabled (as the row versions won't be available).

I did test though to see how it behaved when querying `RCSI_Yes` from `RCSI_No`. This used RCSI.

You can just test this yourself.

**Setup**

```
USE master;
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

IF DB_ID('RCSI_Yes') IS NULL CREATE DATABASE RCSI_Yes;
IF DB_ID('RCSI_No') IS NULL CREATE DATABASE RCSI_No;

GO

ALTER DATABASE RCSI_Yes SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON WITH NO_WAIT
ALTER DATABASE RCSI_No SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF WITH NO_WAIT

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS RCSI_Yes.dbo.T1, RCSI_No.dbo.T1;

CREATE TABLE RCSI_Yes.dbo.T1(C1 INT); INSERT RCSI_Yes.dbo.T1 VALUES (1);
CREATE TABLE RCSI_No.dbo.T1(C1 INT); INSERT RCSI_No.dbo.T1 VALUES (1);

BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE RCSI_Yes.dbo.T1 SET C1 = 2

UPDATE RCSI_No.dbo.T1 SET C1 = 2

SELECT 'Updates complete. Transaction left open for 1 mins'

RAISERROR('',0,1) WITH NOWAIT

WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00';

COMMIT
```

Doing a simple `SELECT` at read committed against `RCSI_Yes.dbo.T1` whilst the setup transaction is open reliably returns `1` irrespective of which database context the command is executed from and `RCSI_No.dbo.T1` reliably blocks.

Combining both of them into a single query as below...

**Test query**

```
USE RCSI_No

DBCC useroptions /*isolation level reported as "read committed" rather than "read committed snapshot"*/

SELECT 'RCSI_Yes' AS DB, C1 FROM RCSI_Yes.dbo.T1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'RCSI_No' AS DB,C1 FROM RCSI_No.dbo.T1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'RCSI_Yes' AS DB, C1 FROM RCSI_Yes.dbo.T1
```

Returns

| DB | C1 |
| --- | --- |
| RCSI_Yes | 1 |
| RCSI_No | 2 |
| RCSI_Yes | 1 |

So in the above case it read `RCSI_Yes` with no blocking and read the version `1` and was then blocked reading `RCSI_No` until the lock on that was released and then read `2` from there. And finally reads `RCSI_Yes` again and the same snapshot row.

The above behaviour differs from

```
SELECT 'RCSI_No' AS DB,C1 FROM RCSI_No.dbo.T1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'RCSI_Yes' AS DB, C1 FROM RCSI_Yes.dbo.T1
```

Which returns

| DB | C1 |
| --- | --- |
| RCSI_No | 2 |
| RCSI_Yes | 2 |

In this case the blocking on `RCSI_No` happens first (before the `RCSI_Yes` branch of the plan is executed) and so my supposition is it doesn't get to creating a transaction in 'RCSI_Yes' context until that version is already committed.

This is somewhat surprising as it is contrary to [the documented behaviour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments)

> present each statement with a transactionally consistent snapshot of the data as it existed **at the start of the statement**